# No confirmation on start date after background check clearing

Tags: job-search, job-offer

I was unemployed and I got a job offer.

Once I accepted the written offer (by signing it) and the background check cleared, I cancelled all the other interviews that I had lined up. But now it's been a week since the BG check has cleared and they still won't give me a confirmed start date. The job offer says upon successful completion of background check, I would start on a mutually acceptable date. I told them I am ready to join asap.

I was told that I will get a start date by a particular date and now that date also has been pushed. I am getting a little nervous.

Should I just start applying for other jobs? What would you guys do?

Comment: You say you accepted the offer. Did you sign a contract already? Also, how was this offer given to you? Written, spoken?

Comment: When I asked them about it, they said they will give me a confirmed start date by a particular date. Once that date came, they said they will get back to me in a few more days.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I just start applying for other jobs? What would you guys do?

**It wouldn't harm to start applying again**, just in case this offer is eventually taken back (unlikely given you already signed it).

For future situations, I suggest you drop all your other options and interviews only after you get an offer, *sign* your contract, and the start date arrives; nothing guarantees that the job is bound to happen before that point.

Comment: I did sign a contract. But the contract did not have a start date.

Comment: That's... odd... what *did* that contract specify?

Comment: Contract has salary benefits and all the other usual stuff. I don't think job offers ever have start dates. There is always a background check after you accept the offer that no one can predict for sure how long it will take.

Comment: Job offers should have start dates (or estimate). Contracts, not necessarily. Anyways, the point is that job-searching again now would hardly harm you, and in fact would be a safe choice to make given things are not clear right now.

Comment: It is a full time job offer. Not a contracting position.

Comment: I looked at my offer and updated the post.

Comment: By contract I was talking about the paper you sign when you take an offer, not implying that this job is contractual. I'll check your update and reflect it in my answer when I get some time

Answer (score 1):

> Should I just start applying for other jobs?

Yes.

This situation is somewhat unusual and your new employers is not behaving as I would consider "normal". You don't know what's going on there, so it would be good insurance policy to keep interviewing and looking.

> What would you guys do?

Try to get the hiring manager or recruiter on the phone. Ask professionally, friendly but firmly what the problem is and what you (or anyone else) can do to move things along. Make sure you don't let them off the hook with an evasive answer: "**Them**: oh, there is some paperwork that's missing", "**You:** I understand. What specific paperwork is missing, who is responsible for this paperwork and how can I help them to get this squared away". You probably can't do anything to really help but this is more a case of the "Squeaky wheel gets the grease"

Answer (score 1):

Show up in person.

It’s harder to ignore an issue that’s physically standing in front of you. If they tell you to buzz off, thank them for their time and tell them you will begin looking for a better fit. It’s a little disingenuous to start searching around with a strong feeling that you already have a job about to start imminently, and this will give you closure on the issue one way or the other.

Good luck.